# Nuxt JS with passport local

Tags: node.js, passport.js, nuxt.js, express-session, passport-local

I'm starting with Nuxt JS trying to migrate an old site with passport local and express-session, I get to make the authentication based on  [this repository](https://github.com/Scharkee/vue-nuxt-passport-bulma-express-boiler) but the main problem comes when I reload the page the users logout, its appears that Nuxt JS it's not saving my user session on the browser. I mostly sure there is something that im forgetting to implement or im not understanding. How could I save my res session token on my user browser?. Btw I have my API running on a separate port, so im not sure if there is any problem on saving  session from other port. Here is my code:

Login.vue

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            error : false,
            form : {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        if(this.$store.state.user) {
            return this.$router.push('/');
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async login () {
                await this.$store.dispatch('login', {
                    username : this.form.username,
                    password:  this.form.password
                });
                this.form.password = '';
                this.form.username = '';
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Store/Index.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const state = () => ({
  user: null,

});

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = user;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req) {
      if (
        typeof req.session !== "undefined" &&
        typeof req.user !== "undefined"
      ) {
        commit("SET_USER", req.user);
      }
    }
  },
  login({ commit }, { username, password }) {
    return axios({
      method: "post",
      url: this.$axios.defaults.baseURL + "/auth/login",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      data: {
        username,
        password
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.meta.error === true) {
          throw res.data;
        }

        return res.data.user;
      })
      .then(authUser => {
        commit("SET_USER", authUser);
      });
  },

};
```

API Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors') // Srsly. Fuck Cors
const morgan = require('morgan');

const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const passport = require('passport');

const { database } = require('./config/keys');
const config = require('./config/config.json');
require('./lib/bAuth');


app.disable('view cache');
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.port);

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    name: '_hsid',
    key: 'sessionKey',
    secret: config.session_secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MySQLStore(database),
    cookie : {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 *24 * 365,
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
    
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log(`[✔] Website connected and running at port: ${app.get('port')}`))
```

Login Route:

```
app.post('/login', async (req,res,next) => {

    req.query = req.body;

    auth.authenticate('user-login', (err,user,info) => {
        if(user){
            req.logIn(user,(err)=>{
                if(err){
                    return res.json({
                      meta: {
                        error: true,
                        msg: err
                      }
                    });
                }else{
                    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
                        if(!req.user.authenticated){
                            return res.json({
                                meta: {
                                error: true,
                                msg: "Bad credentials"
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            return res.json({
                                meta: {
                                  error: false
                                },
                                user:  bAccess.cleanUser(Object.assign({}, user))
                            });
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            return res.json({
                meta: {
                error: true,
                msg: "Bad credentials"
                }
            });
        }
    })(req,res,next);
});
```

Passport Config:

```
auth.use('user-login', new Strategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, username, password, done) => {
    const _user = await _context.query('select username,password from users where username = ?', username);

    if (!_user[0]) return done(null,false);

    if (!_user[0].password || !await bAccess.verifyPassword(password, _user[0].password)) {
        return done(null, false);
    }

    done(null, _user[0], {scope : '*'});
}, ));

auth.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

auth.deserializeUser(async (user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
```

Comment: session cookies?

Comment: how could i add that ? Sorry for the dumb question im new on this

Comment: actually you already use express-session. I would suggest to locate where the problem could happen

Comment: you can use cookies or localStorage()

Comment: i'm in doubt if it could be because im running my API on different port, but my nuxt project receive my response OK. So really idk well

Comment: i have the same problem, i have 2 separate projects, a nuxt frontend running on port 3000 and a backend running on 8000, my nuxtServerInit has req.session and req.user undefined, how did you fix this?